# The Best Silverlight UI Control Collection

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I'm looking for a good Silverlight control collection to use them in my application.

Can you recomend a good one?

Not problem if it's not free.

Thanks. l.

Comment: NOV UI Controls for Silverlight - http://examplesnovsilverlight.nevron.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Telerik Silverlight Controls](http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight.aspx)

[Blacklight Silverlight Controls](http://mightymeaty.members.winisp.net/blacklight.silverlight/)

Answer (score 0):

While I've not had an opportunity to test the latest versions, you should take a look at the offerings from [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight.aspx), [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/silverlight/line-of-business.aspx#Overview) and [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/Silverlight/).

Answer (score 0):

I saw a few control collections and I found the Telerik products that is provide the best solution for my needs.

Thanks your help!

l.